# Subdomain redirecting to domain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, dns, subdomain

Currently I am setting up a WordPress Multisite. Every customer will have their own subdomain.
So in this example our site is called: [www.example-site.de](http://www.example-site.de). One customer will have his own domain called "www.customerxy.example-site.de"
Unfortunately, sometimes the subdomains redirect to the main domain. If I type "https://customerxy.example-site.de" I was not able to reproduce the problem. Just when I typed "customerxy.example-site.de". I do not know if this has anything to do with it, but this was something I noticed.

I already wrote that it could be, because subdomain and main domain are pointing on the same folder. The .htaccess file shows the following:

"

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://customerxy.example-site.de/$1 [R=301,L] 

# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```

"

If some1 has any idea how to fix this that sometimes the subdomains redirect to the main domain, I'd be so glad. Thank you for every help in advance!

Best regards

Benjamin

Comment: The only _external_ redirect in what you have shown, is the redirect to `https://customerxy.example-site.de/$1`, if the whole thing was not accessed via port 443 already. (Which means you would be redirecting to that particular subdomain for _all_ HTTP requests, you will need something _dynamic_ in this place.) So if you typed `http://customerxy.example-site.de` in your browser, that part could apply - but then you should not land on the main domain.

Comment: My guess here would therefor be, that those redirects originate elsewhere, and not directly in the .htaccess code you have shown. Could either be a faulty HTTP-to-HTTPS redirect set in the hosting panel; or maybe WordPress itself is redirecting, based on what sites are configured and with what URLs exactly.

Comment: And you really should sort out whether you want that old fashioned "www." prefix to your host names or not. You keep mixing both variants in the question.